# How do I attach a .xlsx file to LaTex document

Tags: latex

I've been trying to attach a .xlsx file to my LaTex document in overleaf. My question is: is this even possible, and if so, how do I do it? I know how to do it locally, but not such that external peers can open the attachment from within a PDF like a hyperlink.

I've tried to use the hyperref package but only succeeded in referincing local files.

I figured I could upload my .xlsx file in overleaf and use a command that inputs the file with a optional name such that it can be opened regardless of the user.

Comment: others don't have access to your local file (unless it's a network drive and everyone has access to that). You can try uploading the files and hyperlinking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated package to attach files to your document, the `attachfile` package. This way the file will be part of the pdf itself and distributed along with it.

A short example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{attachfile}

\begin{document}
content...

\attachfile{Workbook1.xlsx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I find the output very ugly. If anyone knows a way of changing the output into some sort of clickable text, please let me know.

Useful answer though.

Comment: @RandomUser If you don't like the icon, you can use `\textattachfile{myfile.cc}{extractmy source code}`